# Get specific tags from specific user instagram API

Tags: javascript, php, instagram

I'm using javascript and php.

Instagram's API will only return 20 results at a time. I can get a user's feed OR tags from all users but not a combination of both.

**For example:**

If I do a search for all the tags with "selfie", but only want results from the users `@ladygaga` and `@justinbieber`, Instagram will only return 20 results from everybody with #selfie. Since the tag "selfie" is so widely uses, it's extremely unlikely that any of those results will have `@ladygaga` or `@justinbieber` in them.

In which way can I use pagination or any other method to filter search results by tag and user.

Comment: If you only care about those two handles, could you instead search by user and filter based on the contents of the posts?

Comment: @jterry It would still only be 20 results, if they have 20 photos, then the 21st is #selfie, it would return nothing.